# Conversion from Orthodox to Syro Malabar Syrian Catholics

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, marriage, canon-law, conversion

I am a Syro Malabar Syrian Catholic working in Dubai from Gujarat (from Kerala). I am getting married to a Swiss Citizen (Malayali) who is born and brought up in Switzerland and is working in Dubai.

His parents are Orthodox and he was baptized as an Orthodox but at the age of 12 or 13 he decided to be a Roman Catholic. He got the sacrament of holy communion and confirmation in a Roman Catholic church in Switzerland. Presently he is a member of a Catholic  church in Dubai.

We are planning to get married in October but in the Syro Malabar Rite. Can anyone tell me what papers are required for us to get married as one of the certificates the church is asking for is the baptism certificate and his baptism certificate mentions he is an orthodox. I heard he can convert by professing the faith. Can someone tell me how I should move fowrard with the same to get him professed in faith. Is there any written letter he needs to submit to the prient or bishop saying he would like to convert?

We also need an NOC from Dubai and the place we belong to but for him from the priest in Zurich church that he goes to have denied saying that they dont give a paper saying he is the member of the church or that he is not married before.

Can someone who knows canon law or has slightest idea of what to do help us.

Thanks

Comment: Your would-be-husband does not have to prove himself to be Catholic in order to get married . The Catholic Church does permit inter-denomination marriage. Try for a certificate of baptism and no-marriage-certificate from the Orthodox Church, which should be acceptable to the church in which the marrage is to be solemnised.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Would you like to make that an answer? You are correct.

Comment: Well, I will have to Google to substantiate.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan But it is relevant for some formalities if he is Catholic, so the parish should try to clarify this.

Comment: @Ash I think your problem is that the Swiss parish don't give you the paper. I'm really sure they have to confirm that he converted and they have no information about a marriage in their records. I suspect they make a fuss, because they don't have the records of the Orthodox parish. So maybe it is the solution to get a certificate from both parishes that they know of no marriage. The conversion to Roman Catholic is done, so no need for another conversion, but the Swiss Parish has to confirm that. No answer, because I don't have the laws that state the details.